# DIV height and width

Tags: css

I would like to have a div with a width that fills 100% of the viewport and a height 10% of the same div's width. I've been trying `height: 10vw;` however it does not work well with all browsers (especially firefox and on Android). Is there anything I've been missing? What should be the best way to achieve it?

Thanks!

UPDATED: it's the same div. Wanted a single DIV with the width that fill 100% and a height 10% of it.

Comment: `html {height:100%;}`

Comment: You wrote: "100% of the viewport width and 10% of the div width" Are you asking for a width and height or two separate div's? Please edit to clarify.

Comment: What do you want to put _inside_ the div?

Comment: div will have a background and a few text. does it matter?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work on all browser because they hasn't implemented yet. In Android it doesn't works yet and in Firefox it should work on version 19 and up: http://caniuse.com/viewport-units

You could put your element in an absolute position instead, and give it a height of 100%. It will cover the 100% of the height of the first element with a position different to static, and if there isn't any element with it, then it will cover root's height. And **the root is the viewport**.

```
div {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
}
```

There's also a [polyfill](https://gist.github.com/LeaVerou/1347501) to support vw/vh/vm units.

Comment: I wanted the div's height to be 10% of it's width (or viewport's width). Not 100% height.